# Why listbox ignore that same file add twice at once?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I create a listbox as playlist for media player.

But its ignore same file adding twice at once .

How can I add same file add (twice or more) on listbox at once .

See My Code:

Xaml:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listbox4" Drop="listbox4_Drop" </ListBox>

<Button x:Name="load" Content="Load" Width="76" Click="load_Click" />
```

Xaml.cs:

```
    private Dictionary<string, string> fileDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();   

    private void load_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
   Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog ofd = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.DefaultExt = ".mp3";
    ofd.Filter = "All|*.*";
    ofd.Multiselect = true;
    Nullable<bool> result = ofd.ShowDialog();
    if (result == true)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < ofd.FileNames.Length; i++)
        {
            var filePath = ofd.FileNames[i];
            var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            fileDictionary.Add(fileName, filePath);
            listbox4.Items.Add(fileName);
            listbox4.SelectedItem = fileName;
        }
    }
    }

    private void listbox4_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {

            string[] droppedFilePaths =
                e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true) as string[];

            foreach (string droppedFilePath in droppedFilePaths)
            {
                var filePath = droppedFilePath;
                var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                fileDictionary.Add(fileName, filePath);
                listbox4.Items.Add(fileName);
                listbox4.SelectedItem = fileName;
            }

        }
    }
```

Please help me.

When I open or drop same file it's ignore and see error.

Otherwise it's working fine.

**Error** shown this statement:

```
fileDictionary.Add(fileName, filePath);
```

Please help me anyone

Comment: Do you actually know what a dictionary is? ;-) Maybe you should take a look,,.

Comment: The "Error" literally says what's wrong: "An element with the same key already exists in the Dictionary..."

Answer (score 2):

A *dictionary* can only contain one entry for any given key. So if you try to add another value using the same key you get a error.

Comment: That depends on what you want to achieve. If you want multiple instances don't use a dictionary at all, or make the corresponding value a `List`. If you just need one value, check whether the key is already contained and don't try to add the value if so. You can also reassign a new value using `dict[key] = newValue`.

Comment: If I dont use dictionary I can not use filename & filepath at a time.

Comment: @TaniaAkter: Of course you can, you just have to create a class that has two properties.

Comment: @TaniaAkter: This is besides this question. So far you have failed to demonstrate a grasp of the most basic of methodologies. You might be better of reading some [introductory documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109.aspx).

Comment: I am not understood